SQLAlchemy + Python Mapping, Do I have to map every column from SQL Server DB or can I map only the columns I need?
One of many tables in SQL Server database has far more columns than I need, upwards of 40-50, and I only need 5 or 6 of them. Can I map only the columns I need?

The answers below are correct, no you do not need to map every column or table. For any mapping of existing databases, I'd suggest using sqlacodegen. It allows for easy table reflection, with little to no input. Support for SqlAlchemy >2.0 currently only published on github.

This worked great once I got it going. Thanks!

Yes.
From docs.sqlalchemy.org
Sometimes, a Table object was made available using the reflection process described at Reflecting Database Objects to load the table’s structure from the database. For such a table that has lots of columns that don’t need to be referenced in the application, the include_properties or exclude_properties arguments can specify that only a subset of columns should be mapped.

The link you provided says it's legacy. Do you know if it still compatible with the latest version of SQLAlchemy?

@SkimMaster86 same in v2.0 https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/declarative_tables.html#include-exclude-cols

You don't need to map every column from your MSSQL database in SQLAlchemy. You can map only the columns you need by specifying them in your model. It will only interact with the columns defined in your model.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Short answer: Yes, you can.

For such a table that has lots of columns
that don’t need to be referenced in the application, the
include_properties or exclude_properties arguments can specify that
only a subset of columns should be mapped

Read more details on SQLAlchemy docs
